# How to read a HTML json file and get elements with a specific ID or class?

Tags: python

I have the following function:

```
def html_dict_search(html_dict, selector):
```

where

```
 html_dict = json.load(f)
```

and  `selector` is the class/id name.

Something like this should be returned by the function for selector=.headline-item:

```
     {
         "name": "li",
         "attrs": {
             "class": "headline-item"
         },
         "text": "one",
         "children": []
     },
     {
         "name": "li",
         "attrs": {
             "class": "headline-item"
         },
         "text": "two",
         "children": []
     }
```

I cant seem to be able to think of a way to do this nor can I find anything good to read. Any kind of suggestions or ideas are most welcome.

Comment: Have a look at https://pypi.org/project/html2json/

Comment: Can you not save what is returned from that function in a dictionary and access the elements you want by their id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension to filter the collection like this

```
html_json = [{
     "name": "li",
     "attrs": {
         "class": "headline-item"
     },
     "text": "one",
     "children": []
 },
 {
     "name": "li",
     "attrs": {
         "class": "headline-item"
     },
     "text": "two",
     "children": []
 },
 {
     "name": "li",
     "attrs": {
         "class": "subtitle-item"
     },
     "text": "two",
     "children": []
 }]
headline_items = [element for element in html_json if element["attrs"]["class"] == "headline-item"]
```

Which will yield the following data in `headline_items`

```
[{'name': 'li',
  'attrs': {'class': 'headline-item'},
  'text': 'one',
  'children': []},
 {'name': 'li',
  'attrs': {'class': 'headline-item'},
  'text': 'two',
  'children': []}]
```